# Nested iText PdfPTable border width

Tags: java, border, itext, itextpdf

I'm using iTextPdf for pdf generation and I'm creating nested table using the below code.

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
PdfPTable nestedTable = new PdfPTable(2);
table.addCell(nestedTable);
```

Now, I want the border width of `table` to be 0, i.e invisible. I've checked the api and several posts on SO but I couldn't find anything substantial. Is there a way to do so ?

I'm using iText version 5.1.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In iText PDF api there is no such property to manipulate border directly however as `PdfPCell` extends `Rectangle` it has `setBorder` to manipulate the border. So I've just used the same as a workaround as provided below:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
PdfPTable nestedTable1 = new PdfPTable(1);
PdfPTable nestedTable2 = new PdfPTable(1);

PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("StackOverflow"));
newCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);

nestedTable1.addCell(cell);
nestedTable2.addCell(new Phrase("StackOverflow"));

cellOne = new PdfPCell(nestedTable1);
cellTwo = new PdfPCell(nestedTable2);

cellOne.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);

table.addCell(cellOne);
table.addCell(cellTwo);
```

Output:

```
                            _______________________
                           |                       | 
      StackOverflow        |     StackOverflow     |
                           |_______________________|
```